# Resizing media Partition, safe?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I recently switched to Ubuntu 12.04. I have two storage drives, my SSD with Ubuntu and the root filesystem installed on it, and my 1TB HDD with movies and other large data files.  I wiped the SSD on the installation, but I kept the media drive as is (for the installation).

I decided I wanted to use ext4 format instead (mostly because Plex has issues with NTFS and the permissions not being there).  Because the amount of data took up ~200GB of space, I don't have another drive to move it onto temporarily, so I created a 700GB partition on the unused portion of my HDD, formatted to ext4, moved my data over (fixed the permissions), and currently deciding on how to continue.

- I can directly resize the current ext4 partition to fill the HDD, but because the data is sitting in the middle it wants to move it to the start of the partition.  So I get a warning.  How dangerous is it to go this route?  I can't back up the HDD.
- My other option is to format the old NTFS to ext4, move the files back to that partition, delete the second ext4 partition and resize the one I just formatted to fill the HDD.  I'm not %100 certain that my files would be safer as they wouldn't need to be moved but it would seem like it.

Am I correct?

TL;DR:

Have a 1TB HDD with two partitions, an empty one (no format) take up the first ~300GB of the drive, and one with my data files (~200GB) in ext4 that fills the rest of the HDD.  The data starts at the begining of the second partition so resizing the second to fill the HDD would require moving the files while being formatted (I assume).  Is this safe? If not I'll just go the second route, more time consuming is all (took nearly an hour for my files to be moved last time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much more safe to go second route.

- if something goes wrong, you'll have *at least* one copy of data intact
- if something goes wrong while formatting & moving data (the first route) you will end up with half-moved data and broken partition table.
- it will take almost the same time to copy 200 GB from one partition to another (the same amount of data needs to be moved)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be safe you could just format the unused space as another drive, so you have two partitions, then use one for music and the other for video. It's a safe option.

I have had problems expanding a partition towards the start of the drive (I assume because it moves the file pointers) but no trouble expanding the partition towards the end of the drive.  So, if you realy needed to use all of the space, I would create a new partition in the free space at the start of the drive, copy the files over, and then delete the old partition and expand the new partition towards the end of the drive.

If you can live with the setup you have you may want to go with option one until the price of drives drops to the point that you can afford a backup drive before doing anything.